# Calling a Java method from a sqlite trigger (android)

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers, callback

I want registered callback method using sqlite trigger
for example,

```
public void printLog(){
 Log.i("TAG","1 row added");
}
```

this method calling after insert any row in sqlite.

Is it possible?

How to do that?

Comment: why not make this call below the code, wherever you `insert` a record? Why make a `call` via a `trigger`?

Comment: That is just example. I want notification after changes sqlite dbs.

Comment: Why don't you check the return value of the db insert api? It'll return you the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite provides [Data Change Notification Callbacks](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html). I don't think that Android exposes them directly but it does have for example CursorAdapter which provides some change notifications.

You can use also use the [getContentResolver().registerContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) but unfortunately it doesn't tell you what kind of change was made, it could be a delete, insert or update.

If you control the ContentProvider that interfaces with the DB then you could fire an Intent or use [getContentResolver().notifyChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) to send a special Uri notification that identifies both the table and action. An example Uri you could notify with might be: content://my-authority/change/table-name/insert

But even then you don't know exactly which rows were effected by the change.

Seems like triggers that write to a change log table will guarantee you hear about all changes regardless of where they came from, and you can know the exact id and action that occurred. Unfortunately it means slower inserts/updates/deletes and it means you probably need a Service of some kind to process and delete changes.

I'd love to hear if these is some better solution out there!

Answer (score 0):

You can set content observer this link will help Receives call backs for changes to content http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html