# Observing @Relation changes in a DataBase

Tags: java, android, annotations, relational-database

If I something like the following:

```
@Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "fk_id", entity = User.class)
private List<User> users;
```

This `list` is a model which gets updated via `LiveData`.

But I want to be able to update this when I detect changes to the User table. Right now, it only picks up what exists in the DB, but whenever an update happens to the user table, this list does not get updated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have not been very specific in what you are doing or want (which database you use, who is updating the database...).

> But I want to be able to update this when I detect changes to the User
>   table. Right now, this only picks up what exists in the DB but
>   whenever an update happens to the user table, this list does not get
>   updated. Any suggestions?

## Option 1

If you are doing the `update/insert/delete` in the *same* app as the `List users`, then you can easily update your `List` in your code.

## Option 2

If *another* app/service is updating the database, I suggest you use a [trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to update your `List`.

See http://www.coderconsole.com/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html for an example.

Detecting the change in Java is tricky, see [Calling a Java method from a sqlite trigger (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268684/calling-a-java-method-from-a-sqlite-trigger-android) .

Here is an example where you use a `ContentObserver` to monitor your `Sqlite` database (the flat file itself) https://gist.github.com/JBirdVegas/3874450

## Option 3

If another app/service is updating the database, you can use a [BroadcastReceiver](https://www.journaldev.com/10356/android-broadcastreceiver-example-tutorial) to pick up the changes.